# Proving a set of points is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can someone please help me prove that the set of points $\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\geq 1\}$, $n$ being a positive integer, is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$?

I understand that in order for a set to be closed it must contain all of its limit points, but I am not sure if I should prove this statement through its complement or another way. 
Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Find a limit point that is not in the set.  The set actually only *has* one limit point and it isn't in the set.  Do you know what that limit point is.  (Hint:  What is $\lim \frac 1n$?)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Is $0$ a limit point of your set?

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, we get the sequence converging to $0$ i.e. $0$ is a limit point. However if you write out the sequence you have $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, .........\}$ you will see that $1/n$ ONLY TENDS to zero but never actually equals zero. Therefore it is not present in the following set. So by your definition of closed sets, this set is not closed.